# what is the best way to enable proguard-rules in android app for protecting our app against reverse engineering

Tags: android, proguard

I am working on a government confidential app and I want to protect our app from reverse engineering. Is there any best way to implement proguard-rules?

I already enabled this

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

And this is my proguard-rules.pro file

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# You can control the set of applied configuration files using the
# proguardFiles setting in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keep class com.bsn.buildingaudit.Model.*{*;}
```

Comment: I think that's right. Do you have something in mind?

Comment: ya I want to know is there any other rules  which I can write in proguard-rule.pro file   like for changing the name of classes methods for high security purpose